# Javascript: How to require using const

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

There's one thing I don't understand about modern Javascript. I see a lot of people discussing whether they should use `var`, `const`, or `let` when requiring new modules. Most people say it's `const` as their first priority and `let` second, but I don't see many people who are fan of `var`. However, this code down below would throw a `error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'other'` error. (**Note**: This error comes from the Typescript compiler, using the `commonjs` flag.)

**main.js**

```js
'use strict';

const A = require('./A.js');
const B = require('./B.js');

// do more stuff
```

**A.js**

```js
'use strict';
const other = require('./other.js');

class A {
    //...
};

module.exports = A;
```

**B.js**

```js
'use strict';
const other = require('./other.js');

class B {
    //...
};

module.exports = B;
```

I'm not sure in which cases it's error-less to use `const`. It seems that it only works when a module is imported in the main module using `const`, and then everything else in other modules have `var` for importing the same module. I'd like to know if I'm missing something. Thanks.

**EDIT:**

This is the code of one of my modules. When I change the `var`s at the top to `const`, the error begins. I've also defined the same imports in other modules that are interconnected.

```
var Datastore = require('nedb');
var validate = require("validate.js");
var path = require('path');


module.exports = class Planet{

    private db_filename : string  = "db/planets.db";

    private ds;

    private static instance : Planet = null;

    private constructor(){      
    }


    init(db_filename : string) : Planet{
        this.ds = new Datastore({ filename: db_filename, autoload: true, timestampData: true });
        return this;
    }


    static get_instance() : Planet{
        if(this.instance == null)
            this.instance = new Planet();
        return this.instance;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking: You can redefine a variable defined with var, you cannot with const/let-defined variables. You should always use const because it throws you errors (as you see) if you accidentally redefine a variable. If you need to modify the variable later on you have to step down to let.

```
// works
var a = 1;
var a = 2;

// error (because var a is defined above)
let a = 1;

let b = 1;
// error (because let b is defined above)
let b = 2;

// error
const b = 1;
// error
const a = 1;


const c = 1;
// error
const c = 2;
// error   
c = 2;
```

I do not know why your typescript-compiler throws an error. Testing this with plain node.js it works perfectly fine.

Comment: My compiler throws an error... but you also said those const's and let's throw an error. I don't understand what you're talking about when you say "I don't know why your typescript....". Isn't it because of the same reason you described?

Comment: Yes and no. If it all was in one file it was that very problem. Because you have different files they do not share one global namespace but one namespace per file. At least this is the case for node.js by its self. I do not know what your typescript-compiler thinks, though. Apparently it does not agree.

Comment: Yeah I agree, it should be separate namespaces. I'd try to see what the heck is going on with the compiler, thanks, now I understand everything. But I'll edit my code and post one of my modules so you can see if there's a mistake in the coding of the module.

Comment: Does your compiler give you a line where the error occurs? I don't see any obvious errors right now.

Comment: Yes, if I change the three imports to const, this appears
src\dao\planets.ts(1,7): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'Datastore'.
src\dao\planets.ts(2,7): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'validate'.
src\dao\planets.ts(3,7): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'path'.
src\dao\users.ts(1,5): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'Datastore'.
src\dao\users.ts(2,5): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'validate'.
src\dao\users.ts(3,5): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'path'.

Comment: ↑ Sorry for the format. The user.ts is a similar file (almost identical). And they are both being imported from a main.ts file. (planet.ts and user.ts aren't importing or exporting each other)

Comment: Tbh i am not a typescript expert. In plain js what you have done appears to be perfectly fine. Look at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html . I think you might actually need a different syntax for importing and exporting your modules.